# Move all columns is list pasting to sheet only once

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy all the columns in the list to a new empty sheet were postback starts on column 1

I want to only postback a single time not for each column separately

I get the error
`TypeError: Cannot find function getValues in object Range,Range,Range`

for
`var sV = sourceRange.getValues();`

Any help is appreciated, thanks

```
function arrMoveCols2_n(){

   arrMoveCols2("Elements","Z", ["Id", "Label", "Email"]);  

}


function arrMoveCols2(SshtName, TshtName, sArr){
var sSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SshtName);
 var sLC = sSheet.getLastColumn();
 var sLR = sSheet.getLastRow();

 var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(TshtName);
  var tRange = tSheet.getRange(1, 1, sLR, sArr.length);

  var sNew = [];
  var sourceRange = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++){
     //Headers to Letters
     sNew[i] = HTL(SshtName, sArr[i]);

     //Get the Source Range of Column to be Moved under
     sourceRange[i] = sSheet.getRange(sNew[i] + '1:' + sNew[i] +sLR);
  };

  var sV = sourceRange.getValues();

  tRange.setValues(sV);
}
```

Helper function

```
//Header to Letter
function HTL(shtName,cheader){
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName).getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(cheader);
      cLetter = NTL(colindex +1);
      return cLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining array of ranges here:

```
sourceRange[i] = sSheet.getRange(sNew[i] + '1:' + sNew[i] +sLR)
```

Hence, you will have to get values of each range individually and append it to your sV array like so:

```
 var sV = []
    for (var a in sourceRange){
     var tempData = sourceRange[a].getValues()
      for (var b in tempData){
       if(a == 0)
         sv[b] = []
       sv[b].push(tempData[b][0]) //If you have more then one column of data
                                  //You will have to include one more loop 
      }
    }
```

Your final code:

```
function arrMoveCols2(SshtName, TshtName, sArr){
 var sSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SshtName);
 var sLC = sSheet.getLastColumn();
 var sLR = sSheet.getLastRow();

 var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(TshtName);
 var tRange = tSheet.getRange(1, 1, sLR, sArr.length);

  var sNew = [];
  var sourceRange = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++){
     //Headers to Letters
     sNew[i] = HTL(SshtName, sArr[i]);

     //Get the Source Range of Column to be Moved under
     sourceRange[i] = sSheet.getRange(sNew[i] + '1:' + sNew[i] +sLR);
  };

  var sV = []
        for (var a in sourceRange){
         var tempData = sourceRange[a].getValues()
          for (var b in tempData){
           if(a == 0)
             sv[b] = []
           sv[b].push(tempData[b][0])
          }
        }
  tRange.setValues(sV);
}
```

Comment: Jack thanks for fixing my code, I will study the explanation to understand what you did